Simplifying Complex Traversal Patterns Involving Multiple Association Types (1:N, M:N, N:1 ...)
I'm working on a data model for a system that represents interconnected entities with complex traversal requirements. Specifically, I have the following scenario:

An EntityA connected to multiple EntityB.
Multiple EntityB has multiple EntityC.
Each EntityC is connected to multiple EntityD
....

The point is to say that many objects are interconnected with each other and these connections may be 1-1, 1-many, many-1 or many-many. Currently, we're using a relationional database (Postgresql) and an ORM to handle database operations.
The abstraction of the data model is such that the entities are thought to be ordered from left to right, resembling a tree. Subsequently, the implementation of this model often "traverse" the entities in this left-right order. Let's take this example for Entities:
A - > B -> C -> D
Taking A as root, we might query to return all C's or D's for that matter.
This behavior is embedded by "linking" each node in the chain to have a parent and child using ORM functionalities, not by using explicit joins between the tables themselves. The association tables representing the connections between these tables are dynamically created (!).
My diagnosis of the data model is that the left-to-right abstraction has added complexity to the implementation. Despite this being a relational data use case, the data model is conceived of as a tree of some sort. The use of ORM has added more opacity to how the system works.
I'm not at all an expert on data modelling and thought this exchange maybe the right place to ask this question since it has elements of database design, but also complexity added by the implementation of the current data model.
Could you please guide me on the following aspects:

If maintaining and ordered (left-to-right) traversal pattern in the database entities is advisable,
Advise on simplifying the implementation of the data model?


What you're describing is a /Hierarchical Database/, like DL/1.  While Relational DBMSs can support this sort of thing, it's not what they're best at.
